# Map C++ Reverse Iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, garbage, reverse-iterator

```
map<int, string>::reverse_iterator& it = temp.rbegin();
```

`it` -> points to garbage key value

`it++` -> points to the correct key value

```
map<int, string>::iterator& it = temp.begin();
```

`it`-> points to the correct key value from beginning.

Please assist.

Comment: Kerrek SB has given the correct answer, but the code you post shouldn't compile: you can't initialize a non-const reference with a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Your statements are incorrect. If `temp` is not empty, then `*temp.rbegin()` is indeed the last value in the map, and `*temp.begin()` is the first value.

(However, the *underlying* iterator of the reverse begin is the ordinary end iterator - but you don't see that unless you call `base()` on the reverse iterator.)

Answer (score 0):

You must have an error in your code that's filling the map.  You can verify this by testing a trivial example such as

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, char> coll;

    // insert elements from 1 to 9
    for (int i=1; i<=9; ++i) {
        coll[i] = static_cast<char>(i+'a'-1); // because adding 96 is less obvious that we're indexing based at letter a
    }

    // print all element in reverse order
    for_each (coll.rbegin(), coll.rend(),
        []( pair<int, char> mapinfo ) { cout << mapinfo.second << " "; } );
    cout << endl;
}
```